# Possible to extend /DEV/SDB1 on Centos machine without downtime/data loss?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, fdisk

on CentOS6 I would like to extend /dev/sdb1 to get more free space:

`df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_www-lv_root
                       18G  2.9G   14G  18% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M  105M  347M  24% /boot
/dev/sdb1             296G  233G   48G  84% /sqldata`

The physical harddisk SDB has already been extended to 600GB in VMWare. Fdisk /dev/sdb1 as follows:

`Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000021cd`

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 644.2 GB, 644245094400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 78325 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07acc91f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       39162   314568733+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2           39163       78325   314576797+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_www-lv_root: 18.9 GB, 18865979392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2293 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_www-lv_swap: 2080 MB, 2080374784 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 252 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

As you can probably see, /dev/sdb1 is not part of a volume group. So i'm not sure how to proceed.

I already created a new partition: /dev/sdb2 as linux LVM:

`fdisk /dev/sdb`

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 644.2 GB, 644245094400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 78325 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07acc91f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       39162   314568733+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2           39163       78325   314576797+  8e  Linux LVM

/dev/sdb2 is a new (empty) partition containing the new 300gb of diskpace. As I cannot affort any downtime really I would like to know how to "merge" sdb1 and sdb2 so I end up with a /sqldata of approx 600gb.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Downtime is very likely required in this environment, a single partition.

EL6 docs warn you to [not attempt a resize on a device in use](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/s2-disk-storage-parted-resize-part). Stop everything using this file system, unmount it, and alter its partition table.

EL7 makes [resizing partitions online possible](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/199573), by deleting, re-creating, and the `partx --update` trick to tell the kernel. You would need to upgrade first, probably to EL8.

---

With LVM instead of partitions, this can be easier. Skip partitioning completely. Create physical volumes on entire devices, such as `/dev/sdb`. Resize the disk, then the PV using it with `pvresize`.  As you are not using LVM, this would be a migration to new LVM storage.